# HTML not correctly parsed in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, parsing, xhtml

With this snippet of HTML, the topmost google link is included in every element under it when shown in Firefox and Chrome.

```
 <div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">
        <div>
            <div>                     
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <a>a tag</a>
                    </div>
                    <img />        
                    <h3>a title</h3>
                    <p>a description</p>
                    <div>a detail</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]

What is causing this parsing issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can't have a div in an anchor, the parser is trying to make sense of you markup and not doing to well.

Comment: Actually, in HTML5 having a `div` in an `a` is perfectly legal.

Comment: Which no parsers care about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dropping the following document into [the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parse error?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="g23">
            <a href="http://www.google.com/">
                <div class="article-bg">
                    <div class="splash-border-right">                     
                        <div class="splash-content-margin">
                            <div>
                                <a href="http://www.google.com/">a tag</a>
                            </div>
                            <img src="http://www.google.com/image.jpg" />        
                            <h3 class="splash">a title</h3>
                            <p>a description.</p>
                            <div class="read-time">a min</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Observe that this document is not valid HTML5. The first error:

> Line 13, Column 65: An a start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.

That is, `a` tags must not include other `a` tags. According to [Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) in the comments, Chrome and Firefox's behavior matches the HTML5 spec's [adoption agency algorithm](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#adoptionAgency) for this scenario. It's funky, but, with invalid code, funky results are to be expected.

Comment: I am surprised I went this many years without creating this error before. Thanks, should have been obvious to me.

Comment: Behaviour is predominantly the [Adoption agency algorithm](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#adoptionAgency). Since HTML5, browsers are not free to do what they like when parsing HTML, no matter what the input.